# Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph API to access User attributes in Azure AD B2C tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I found lot of threads regarding this but not sure if they are still valid at this point of time i.e. Jun 2019

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) which was updated on Jul 2017 says **You must use Azure AD Graph API'to manage users in Azure AD B2C directory**

[image]

But at the same time [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) says **As of February 2019, we started the process to deprecate some earlier versions of Azure Active Directory Graph API in favor of the Microsoft Graph API.**

[image]

I found [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) which has road map for AAD Graph and Micorsoft Graph.  But still not clear weather we should use **Microsoft Graph** or **Azure AD Graph** for B2C tenant.  I couldn't find any example how to fetch `User attributes` using `Microsoft Graph`

**Question**

Should I still keep on using 'Azure AD Graph'if I am dealing with B2C tenant?

Answer (score 1):

You must use Azure AD Graph API to manage users in an Azure AD B2C tenant since Microsoft Graph doesn't support a few of the user properties (including the **creationType** property) that are used by Azure AD B2C.

Comment: the creationType property is now supported in the Microsoft Graph API